# Template alias as a dependent name

Tags: c++, c++11, template-aliases

How to call a template function based on a dependent template alias of another template function?

For instance, there is a template class and a template function, which accepts this class as a template argument:

```
template<typename... T>
struct FooClass {
    static int foo() { return 42; }
};

template<template<typename...> class T>
void printFoo() {
    std::cout << T<>::foo() << std::endl;
}
```

Then, there is a class, which contains a template alias to `FooClass`:

```
struct MyClass {
    template<typename... U>
    using FooAlias = FooClass<U...>;
};
```

Finally, there is another template function, which accepts `MyClass` as a template argument and uses its `FooAlias` to call `printFoo` with an appropriate type:

```
template<typename T>
void lookUpAndPrintFoo() {
    // printFoo<FooClass>();            //< works
    // printFoo<MyClass::FooAlias>();   //< works
    printFoo<typename T::FooAlias>();   //< does not compile
}

int main() {
    lookUpAndPrintFoo<MyClass>();
    return 0;
}
```

If I use the desired class directly or its alias, which does not depend on a template argument, everything is fine. As soon as I try to use a dependent alias, I get this error message:

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of 'void lookUpAndPrintFoo() [with T = MyClass]':
prog.cpp:26:29:   required from here
prog.cpp:22:32: error: 'typename MyClass::FooAlias' names 'template<class ... U> using FooAlias = struct FooClass<U ...>', which is not a type
  printFoo<typename T::FooAlias>();
                                ^
```

What is the proper way how to pass `T::FooAlias` to `printFoo()`?

Comment: `T::template FooAlias`

Comment: But why not `typename T::template FooAlias`?

Comment: A template is not a type.